# El método toUpperCase no cumple la condición en este algoritmo en Javascript a menos que se introduzcan números

Tags: javascript, condiciones, else

En este algoritmo intenté hacer funcionar la condición para el método toUpperCase pero no funciona, a menos que se introduzcan números, pero si son letras en minúsculas, no pasa nada ni sale el mensaje advirtiendo el usuario que introduzca mayúsculas, como debería ser.

```
let nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
let categoria = prompt("Ingrese categoría: A, B o C")



if (nombre == nombre.toUpperCase()){
    console.log("Hola "+ nombre.toUpperCase() +" Debe ingresar su nombre en MAYUSCULA \n");
    nombre=prompt("ingrese su nombre en Mayuscula")
}
else if((nombre == "") && (categoria== "")){
    console.log("No se ha registrado ingreso de datos");
}
else if(nombre != "" && categoria==""){
        console.log("Hola "+nombre+", no ha ingresado ninguna categoría");
}
else if((nombre=="") && ((categoria == "A" )|| (categoria == "B") || (categoria == "C"))){
    console.log("No hemos registrado su nombre, la categoría ingresada es " +categoria);
}
else if((nombre!="") && ((categoria == "A") || (categoria == "B") || (categoria =="C"))){
    console.log("Hola "+nombre+ " la categoría ingresada es " + categoria);
}
else if((nombre== "") && ((categoria != "A") || (categoria != "B") || (categoria !="C"))){
     console.log("No ha ingresado su nombre y la categoría ingresada es incorrecta");
}
else if((nombre!="") && ((categoria != "A") || (categoria != "B") || (categoria !="C"))){
     console.log("Hola "+nombre+ " la categoría ingresada es incorrecta");
}
else {
    console.error("Error, el valor ingresado no es valido.");
}
```

Comment: Cambia `if (nombre == nombre.toUpperCase())` por `if (nombre !== nombre.toUpperCase())`. Ese es tu error.